# Alternative to long in order to avoid overflowing Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: java, performance, math, long-integer

New to Stackoverflow so please point out anything I can do to improve the quality of my question.

So what my code does (or rather hopes to do) is calculate huge fibonacci numbers modulo a pretty huge *m*. To make the algorithm more efficient, I employ the use of [pisano periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period). In essence, I calculate the pisano period of *m* and then make the calculation of the remainder easier by using the following relation:

> The remainder of the *n* th Fibonacci number (modulo *m*) is equal to the remainder of the *k* th Fibonacci number (modulo *m*) such that *k* = *n* % *p* where *p* is the pisano period of *m*.

In order to calculate the pisano period, I use the following property:

> If the current Fib % *m* = 0 and the sum of all Fib's until now % *m* = 0, then the index of the current Fib is the pisano period of *m*. (Note the index must be greater than 0)

However I run into a problem in this endeavour: To calculate the pisano period, I have to calculate consecutive Fibonacci numbers. The issue arises when the number of Fibonacci numbers that have to be calculate becomes very large, say 100 000. Then the data type long overflows.

To my knowledge, any endeavour to calculate pisano periods will require the calculation of fibonacci's, so the only solution seems to be to replace long with something else. If anyone has any suggestions as to what this replacement might be, I would greatly appreciate it.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class FibHuge {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        long num = in.nextLong ();
        long mod = in.nextLong();

        System.out.println ( getMod(num, mod));
    }

    private static int getMod (long num, long mod) {
        Period per = new Period();

        long period = per.getPeriod (mod);
        int newFibNum = (int)(num % period);

        num = (num % mod);

        Integer ia[] = new Integer [per.al.size()];
        ia = per.al.toArray (ia);

        return ia[newFibNum];
    }
}

class Period {

    ArrayList <Long> al;
    long FNum;
    long SNum;

    Period () {
        al = new ArrayList <Long> ();
        FNum = 0;
        SNum = 1;
    }

    private long getFib (long first, long second){
        return first + second;
    }

    long getPeriod (long mod){
        boolean bool = true;
        long fibcount = 0;

        long currentmod = 0;
        long fib = 0;
        long sum = 0;

        while (bool){
            if (fibcount <= 1){
                currentmod = fibcount % mod;

                al.add (currentmod);

                sum += fibcount;
            }

            else {
                fib = getFib (FNum, SNum);
                FNum = SNum;
                SNum = fib;

                currentmod = (fib % mod);
                al.add (currentmod);

                sum += fib;
            }

            if ( (currentmod == 0 & (sum % mod) == 0) & fibcount > 0){
                return fibcount;
            }
            fibcount++;
        }

        return mod; //essentially just to satisfy the return condition
    }
}
```

Comment: *The issue arises when the number of Fibonacci numbers that have to be calculate becomes very large, say 100 000.* - I think you have wrong feeling about Fibonacci numbers. They grow exponentially fast - the range of long is exceeded by the 93rd Fibonacci number.

Comment: @Leon Oh well, that's much worse than I thought. Even though I knew they grew exponentially, I had no idea long would pass out so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use BigInteger unless your modulus is too large to fit into a `long` in which case I suspect you will run out of memory trying to find the solution.

Instead of calculating the n-th Fibonacci number and then performing a modulus, you can calculate the n-th Fibonacci after modulus using this property

```
(a + b) % n = (a % n + b % n) % n;
```

In other words you only need to keep adding the modulus of the number in each iteration. You can save all the modulus values in a Set and when you get a repeated result, you have a period. You can store the iteration number with the result and use this to calculate the period.

In fact modulus is kind of expensive but since you will only ever sum a number which is less than 2 * modulus you can simply do

```
long c = a + b; // Fibonacci
if (c >= modulus) c -= modulus; // the only real change you need for modulus.
```

As Java uses a condition move rather than an actual branch this is much faster than using `%`

I can't think of much more details you need to know without writing the code for you.

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately I can't use it unless I crank out a new property for identifying the recurrence in the period, that is, the sum of the fibonacci numbers % m. This is kind of an integral part of my code, as it is one of two things which indicate that the sequence is repeating.

Comment: @Airdish this is why you need a Map of value to the last count that number last appeared. As soon as you get a duplicate have you know the period.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand. Duplicates often occur within the sequence before the period actually reiterates. The only identifying pattern is that each iteration starts with 0, 1.

Comment: @Airdish Disregard the Set/Map idea. Simply run your algorithm taking advantage of the modulo arithmetic property brought to your attention by Peter. I.e. don't keep track of `fib` and `sum` in your loop, instead keep track of `fib % mod` and `sum % mod`.

Comment: @Airdish if you know what pattern to look for, you don't need to remember the previous values.

Comment: Thanks alot Peter Lawrey and @Leon for your ideas. My program's really fast now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), but take note that it will be much slower, but with infinite size.

Comment: How much slower? The problem requires a maximum runtime of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: 1.5 seconds is kind of meaningless without knowing the processor, clock speed and how many calculations you need to do. `BigInteger` may work fine but you probably won't know until you try it.

Comment: *"How much slower?"* - Try it and see.

Comment: Note: you don't actually need BigInteger to solve this problem unless the modulus is very large (too large to store all the results in memory) See my answer.